# Complexity of Computing Volume of Convex Polytope

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, np-complete, computational-geometry

Given a convex polytope $\{x\in \mathbb R^n | Ax\leq b\}$ where $A$ is a matrix, and $b$ is a vector, and inequality between two vectors (like $Ax\leq b$) means inequality between their components ($\forall i : (Ax)_i \leq b_i$).

Is it NP-complete to compute its volume? Or are there efficient algorithms for doing that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the site. We do expect you to do some research before asking here. Googling for "volume of convex polytope" seems to give lots of useful information, including a very relevant [Math Overflow question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/979/48111).

Comment: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.42.7953